# Perl Regex substitution - capturing and executing at same time $1

Tags: regex, perl

Using Perl to spit out HTML text, I'd like to highlight in yellow an asterisk and leading/trailing letter if there's no space in between. Otherwise, if there are spaces around the asterisk, I want to highlight the asterisk in cyan. Here's what I'd like as far as inputs / outputs.

```
Input 1 : word*
Output 1: wor<span class='bcy'>d*</span>

Input 2 : *word
Output 2: <span class='bcy'>*w</span>ord

Input 3 : word * word
Output 3: word <span class='bcc'>*</span> word
```

I'm using the following, but losing that leading/trailing letter and asterisk since `$1` is used in execution instead of capturing. Is there a way to do both ?

```
$phr =~ s/(\*\S|\S\*)|\*/$1 ? '<span class=\'bcy\'>$1<\/span>' : '<span class=\'bcc\'>*<\/span>'/eg;
```

Answer (score 1):

What comes in the replacement side with `/e` modifier must be correct Perl code, and I am getting a little lost trying to trace through your (well meant) quotes and escapes.<sup>†</sup>

Here is a fresh take on it

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $span_beg_1 = q(<span class='bcy'>);
my $span_beg_2 = q(<span class='bcc'>);
my $span_end   = q(</span>);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    s{ (\*\S|\S\*) | \* }
     { $1 ? $span_beg_1 . $1 . $span_end : $span_beg_2 . q(*) . $span_end }egx;

    say 
}
    
__DATA__
word*
*word
word * word
```

The [DATA](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Special-Literals) is Perl's builtin filehandle which reads line by line data appearing after `__DATA__`.

The [q()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) is an operator form of single quotes, very handy for cleanly quoting string literals which may then freely use quotes.

The exact structure of constants I set up above can surely be simplified and/or improved.

This prints

```
wor<span class='bcy'>d*</span>
<span class='bcy'>*w</span>ord
word <span class='bcc'>*</span> word
```

---

<sup>†</sup> For one, `'<span class=\'bcy\'>$1<\/span>'` won't do what is expected (consider `'a$1c'`), as `$1` isn't interpolated. Perhaps `"a${1}b"` would do it, and then given the special nature of `$1` even `"a$1b"` goes.

So it appears that if you just replace the single quotes around the HTML elements with the double ones, so to interpolate the `$1` inside, that it works.  Then you can remove the escapes in front of single quotes in those elements, as well.

But then just better extract those constants anyway.  It's so much easier to read and ensure that it's all the way you want it.

Comment: I don't understand it but it works. I was getting wor* with the asterisk yellow but losing the d. Now I'm getting word* with d* yellow as you said. I'll have to study what's happening. Thank you. And I used variables for the spans like you did.

Comment: This works for me using double quotes works per comment above! Perhaps using variables to eliminate the single quotes helps too? Sorry I used shorter variable names here. $phr =~ s/(\*\S|\S\*)|\*/$1 ? "$sp1$1$spe" : "$sp2\*$spe"/eg;  I've always used s///, I've never seen s{ } { }

Comment: @user3055937 Glad to hear it works for you!  I'll explain it when I get a moment.

Comment: @user3055937   As for `s///`, one can use practically any delimiters; even different sets like `s{...}[...]` (I'm not advertising that, just saying that even that works.) I really like `s{}{}` as they clearly delineate the code.  One can do that with the match operator as well, where with  `//` we don't an `m` in front (which strictly should be there) but with others we do, `m{}`. I'll post a link to docs for it.

Comment: "_I don't understand it_" -- not sure which parts but here's a description. A `s///e` (with `/e`) needs code in the replacement side. And we have: a ternary operator, with: `$sp1 . $1 . $spe`, so `$sp1` and `$1` and `$spe` concatenated (with `.` operator), and similarly in the other term. (Or `"$sp1 ${1} $spe"`, which may be written with just `$1`, without braces, because `$1` is special and the interpreter "knows" the variable.) So the strings and `$1` are evaluated and joined. And that's it -- the rest of the logic is the same as what you had in the question.

Comment: ... the only thing in the question is that under the single quotes variables are _not_ interpolated (evaluated), so you get a string with the literal `$` and `1` characters. It seems that that was the only mistake.  (But when you replace the single quotes with double, under which `$1` _is_ interpolated, then you don't need to escape the single quotes inside the string anymore.)   I still think that it is better to put those larger strings in variables first.

Comment: As for documentation about delimiters, perhaps this [section in `perlop`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs) is most explicit.  Then see [regex quote-like operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) in the same page, and see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)  and [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) (search for the word "delimiter")

Answer (score 0):

I find separate regexes for such problems much easier to understand and maintain as a case distinction is necessary anyway. Up to your use case the `[a-z]` character class should maybe be replaced by `[A-Za-z]` or `\w`.

The *e* modifier is also not needed in the following code:

```
$phr =~ s{([a-z])\b\*} {<span class='bcy'>$1*</span>}g;
$phr =~ s{\*\b([a-z])} {<span class='bcy'>*$1</span>}g;
$phr =~ s{\b \* \b}   { <span class='bcc'>*</span> }g;
```